# what does it mean that Interrupt that is irrelevant to the system data protected by the critical section

Tags: interrupt-handling, rtos

how does it differ for interrupt handler in preemptable os to access shared data structure in case of interrupt that is relevant or irrelavent to system data protected by critical section?also difference between interrupt that is Irrelevant and relevant to system data?

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are asking.  Perhaps some example code would help.  You appear to be asking for an explanation of some term or phrase that you have heard or read; so you might quote precisely the phrase or provide a citation, because your phrasing  is unfortunately somewhat garbled English; I am left asking what your question means.

Answer (score 0):

When execution is in interrupt hanldler, then there is no protected data and no critical section. Interrupt handler execution happens at previleged mode. There can be some exceptions, based on OS, HW etc.